# Using spring as configurator

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

I have a server application. Now I'm using Spring not only to inject dependencies, but also to config my application. Something like this:

```
<bean id="server" class="foo.bar.Server">
    <property name="host" value="${config.host}"/>
      <property name="someBean">
      <ref bean="someBean"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My colleague sad that configuring application in Spring is not obvious and we should avoid this. I see logic in his words, because Spring is for dependence injection and server port is not dependency, isn't it? But for me configuring application is Spring is very convenient and obvious. Is my colleague right?

Comment: No, your colleage is not correct, it is correct to pass property elements using spring

Comment: Ask your colleague how he would configure the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring in Spring is **simple**, **clear** and **maintainable**.

This way you can easily create several instances with different properties.